# Check if <HTML> has attribute or Not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input value of HTML text with html tags inside this value like below

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/khn9d5me/9/)**

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" value="<!DOCTYPE html><html amp4email><head></head><body>...Content...</body></html>" id="ampHtml" />
```

**Attempted Script:**

```
var __amp_content = $("#ampHtml").val();
var __attr = jQuery(__amp_content).find('html').attr('amp4email');
if (typeof __attr !== 'undefined' && __attr !== false) {
    alert('Fail');
} else {
    alert('Success...');
}
```

How can I show alert based on:

- if html has amp4email show alert as **Success**
- Else show alert as **Fail**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like jQuery is including only the contents of the `<body>` tag after parsing, which in this case is only a text node. The info you want isn't in the resulting object.

One option would be to use DOMParser instead. There's no need for a big library like jQuery for something like this anyway.

```js
const ampContent = document.querySelector('#ampHtml').value;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(ampContent, 'text/html');
const attribute = doc.documentElement.getAttribute('amp4email');
console.log('Has attribute:', attribute !== null);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="<!DOCTYPE html><html amp4email><head></head><body>...Content...</body></html>" id="ampHtml" />
```

Comment: Thanks **@CertainPerformance**, your answer is working as expected. I am **Accepting** and **Upvoting** your answer. Keep up the great work